# making nested ajax calls

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am trying to make a HN clone with vanilla JS.

JS CODE:

```
var apiResult = document.getElementById("apiResult");

function apiContent() {
var url_end = ' https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json? 
print=pretty';
var apiCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
var links = [];

apiCall.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        var apiData = JSON.parse(apiCall.responseText);

        for( var i = 0; i < apiData.length; i++){

            var url = 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' ;
            var c_url = apiData[i] + '.json?print=pretty';
            var final_url = url + c_url;
            links.push(final_url);
        }
            // console.log(links);

            for(var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
                var a = links[j];
                var secondRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                secondRequest.onload =  function() {
                var secondData = JSON.parse(secondRequest.responseText);
                console.log(secondData);
            }
            secondRequest.open('GET', a, true);
            secondRequest.send();
            }       
    }
    else {
        console.log('Unable to fetch data');
    }
}
apiCall.open("GET", url_end, true);
apiCall.send();


}
```

The first api call 'url_end' gives the ID of the top 500 stories, it just returns the ID and nothing else. So to fetch the content corresponding to the story ID i'm making an another AJAX call but this time the url is updated with the ID but its not working.

How do I make this work??

Comment: youd better use the async feature see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: one suggestion here I've is try to avoid the number of calls to your backend, instead write some some backend logic which will return all your topstories along with its details. that will reduce the complexity.

Comment: that's the problem i'm unable to do it in one go

Answer (score 0):

I have created the sample example. You need a closure to call multiple ajax inside the for the loop. Sample JSON hosted on http://jsonstore.online Documents: http://jsonstore.online/#!/documentation.

**WORKING JS CODE:**

```js
var apiResult = document.getElementById("apiResult");
function apiContent() {
var url_end = 'https://api.jsonstore.online/api/PsrWFAEwRVWXXU9y/cities';
var apiCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
var links = [];
apiCall.onload = function() {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        var apiData = JSON.parse(apiCall.responseText);
        for( var i = 0; i < apiData.length; i++){
            var final_url = 'https://api.jsonstore.online/api/PsrWFAEwRVWXXU9y/cities?id='+apiData[i].id ;
            links.push(final_url);
        }
        console.log(links); // Print Link Array
        
        for(var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
         (function(a){
              let secondRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
              secondRequest.onload =  function() {
                let secondData = JSON.parse(secondRequest.responseText);
                console.log(secondData);
              }
              secondRequest.open('GET', a, true);
              secondRequest.send();
           })(links[j]);
        } 
        
    }
    else {
        console.log('Unable to fetch data');
    }
}
apiCall.open("GET", url_end, true);
apiCall.send();
}
apiContent();
```